# Why is $\mathbf A$.d$\mathbf A$=AdA? Here, $\mathbf A$ is a vector.

Tags: vector-analysis

Why is $\mathbf A$.d$\mathbf A$=|$\mathbf A$||d$\mathbf A$|cos $\alpha$=AdA?

$\mathbf A$.d$\mathbf A$=|$\mathbf A$||d$\mathbf A$|cos $\alpha$ is fine. It comes from the dot product rule. But why is it furthur equal to A.dA?

Here, $\mathbf A$ is a vector.

Comment: $d \bf A$ is a small displacement along $\bf A$ ?

Answer (score 0):

It is so because $ d \vec A$ is taken along the same direction as that of $ \vec A$ i.e., normal to the plane. So ,the angle between the two is $ 0$